# DbContext instance vs Scope instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Why Entity Framework uses `AddDbContext` method for dependency injection instead of Singleton, Scoped, Transient?

With `AddDbContext` method what kind of Service lifetime (Singleton, Scoped, Transient) we've got for every request?

Comment: By default AddDbContext uses Scoped lifetime. It's the most useful for web applications where each request defines a scope. This ensures that the same context will be available during a request's lifetime. Transient is also useful if the context is going to be used only inside an action

Answer (score 0):

The parameterless version of the method results in a **Scoped** lifetime for the `DbContext` and if given, the options:

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddDbContext<TContext>(
        [NotNull] this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
        [CanBeNull] Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction = null,
        ServiceLifetime contextLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped,
        ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped)
        where TContext : DbContext
        => AddDbContext<TContext, TContext>(serviceCollection, optionsAction, contextLifetime, optionsLifetime);
```

`AddDbContext` is just an extension method delivered by Entity Framework Core that **handles the service registration for you under the hood**. You could do all the service registration that is done there yourself, but with this extension method, EFCore makes sure everything is set up as needed.

The method has an **overload** in which you can specify the `ServiceLifetime` yourself (that is called with default parameters from the parameterless overload).

In general, for these kind of questions it's easiest to consult the official documentation:

[EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext Official Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-2.1)

Or to have a deeper understanding, look at the Code on github:

[EF-Core Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore)